# Degree of English penetration in music

Tags: anglais, anglicismes, musique

I'm enjoying some French music, and I notice that English phrases tend to be thrown in now and again. Here are some examples from two artists I've been listening to lately:

**Starmania** (parolier : **Luc Plamondon**)

> [Le monde est stone](http://www.cyberus.ca/%7Erg/ch_p001.htm) (titre d'une chanson)
>
> [J'travaille à l'Underground Café](http://www.comedie2000.com/parole.php3?chanson=complainte_de_la_serveuse_automate&comedie_musicale=starmania) (paroles de "La complainte de la serveuse automate")
>
> [I've got the whole world in my hand](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Nanette_Workman-Ce_soir_on_danse_a_Naziland-lyrics,p02523288) (paroles de "Ce soir on danse à Naziland")
>
> [Ces buildings de verre qui filtrent la lumière](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_renaud_hantson_11363/paroles_il_se_passe_quelque_chose_a_monopolis_388274.html) (paroles de "Il se passe quelque chose à Monopolis")

**Daniel Lavoie**

> [You've got the learn the hard way, baby, et ça c'est ça](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel_Lavoie:%C3%87a_C%27Est_%C3%87a) (paroles de "Ça c'est ça")*

* (Is "ça c'est ça" itself an Anglicism for "that's that", or is it pretty natural-sounding?)

Now, I notice that these examples have in common that they were written in the '70s by Canadian lyricists. But is/was this a general trend, to throw the odd English word or whole line into a song? Are some of these words ("stone", "buildings") ones that would crop up in informal conversation and hence are being used naturally, or are they being used solely for artistic purposes in the song?

I realize that English often comes up in informal French conversation; I'm hoping for an angle on its use in French music specifically. I also realize that there are no hard answers on this, so I'm more or less just doing a sondage on what you've noticed about trends (across decades, across countries, or whatever) in this phenomenon.

Comment: "ça c'est ça" is _not_ natural sounding at all :-)

Comment: I would say that the 70s were quite different, and that at that time, there might have been reasons to admire the culture in the UK or US, esp. in  music. These days, I don't know - there might be a tendency to throw in a few English words for _marketing_ purposes. (PS: nobody uses _stone_ in everyday conversation in France, IMHO :-) But there are plenty of lesser known musicians/music groups that might not use English at all.

Comment: Un article du Figaro: http://www.lefigaro.fr/musique/2007/11/26/03006-20071126ARTFIG00398-pourquoi-ces-francais-chantent-en-anglais-.php et un autre link: https://www.senscritique.com/liste/Artistes_Francais_qui_chantent_en_anglais/210018

Comment: Good point about cultural capital in the era of rock. And thanks for the article link. Interesting line from it: "Simplement, écrire nous est plus facile en anglais qu’en français. Il est difficile de trouver un langage vraiment pop en français." It's funny, because every language of course has different "langages" for different purposes. I wonder why English occupies the French "pop" niche rather than a register of French. And does any English have that feel, or only English language that fills the equivalent niche in an English milieu? :p

Comment: Regarding “which English,” it'd depend on a particular artist’s familiarity w/non-pop English AND on other influences on their lives & creative genius. Eg: Serge Gainsbourg’s 1984 [“Love on the Beat”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_on_the_Beat) has English terms for the titles of (& some lyrics in) 7 of 8 cuts, not all of which (esp. the term “No comment”), can be seen as pop. (He used Eng. terms in 1962 (Black Trombone/Intoxicated Man), which predates his years w/Jane Birkin, so it can’t all be her "fault"!). His lifestyle & desire to shock help explain his use of non-pop English, imo.

Comment: Because the English and Americans invented "le rock". I have zero idea about Canadian French lyricists.

Comment: You must have heard about [For Me Formidable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awanoUsHuhA) from Charles Aznavour, eh? This has to be one of the greatest Frenglish songs ever!

Comment: Je n'avais pas en fait. Merci de l'avoir partagée, c'est très drôle !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a affaire à plusieurs cas différents d'emploi de l'anglais dans un contexte français.

**Stone**
Dans les années 60 et 70 tout un pan de la jeunesse française comprenait le mot au moins depuis la sortie de *Rainy Day Women* (*Blonde on Blonde*, Bob Dylan, 1966) parce que la musique anglo-saxonne commençait à avoir une grande emprise chez les adolescents et ce mouvement de société, initié dans les années 50 avec les chanteurs de rock, a aussi contribué à populariser l'apprentissage de l'anglais en France et à reléguer l'allemand au second plan, l'allemand ayant longtemps été la langue la plus apprise dans les lycées français (je ne dis pas que c'était la seule raison, juste une des raisons).
Dans les années 60 / 70 un ado ou jeune adulte pouvait employer le mot dans une phrase en français, pour aussi bien marquer son appartenance à un groupe que pour empêcher un non initié de comprendre ce qu'il disait, surtout dans une société où parler de drogue était encore plus tabou que de nos jours, l'emploi de l'anglais permettait de braver l'honnêteté*.
Comme le fait remarquer @Lambie, les Français ont repris le mot en laissant tomber le D final. Et c'est sans son D qu'il est répertorié dans les dictionnaires français, [par exemple](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/stone).

**Underground Café**
C'est un nom propre ici donc traduire ne s'impose pas. Mais je pense que pratiquement tout le monde comprend *underground* de nos jours autant que dans les années 60, époque où on a commencé à l'employer. On parle encore en français de « culture underground » même si le terme tend à être remplacé depuis le début du XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle par « culture alternative » (voir à cet effet l'[article de wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_underground) en français sur ce terme).

**I've got the whole world in my hand**
Ici c'est une référence directe au negro spiritual très ancien *He's Got the Whole World In His Hands*, pris et repris par des chanteurs populaires anglophones et non anglophones. Il y a même une chanson populaire  *I've got the whole world in my hand* (Bo Carter, 1920). Je ne pense pas que la citation directe viendrait directement dans une conversation en français mais si on cite une chanson il est normal de citer le titre dans la langue originale.

**You got to learn the hard way baby**
Je parlerais dans ce cas d'une coquetterie de parolier qui a voulu faire bien en mettant une expression anglaise qui collait bien avec son texte.

Quant à **building** ça fait longtemps que le terme est passé dans le vocabulaire français, il figure [dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/building).

---

*Dans la mesure où ce site est fréquenté par des non francophones je pense utile d'expliquer en note l'expression « braver l'honnêteté ».
C'est une référence directe à [Boileau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Boileau)  (*Le latin dans les mots brave l'honnêteté ; Mais le lecteur français veut être respecté*, [Boileau, Art p. II]). Parler dans une langue étrangère (le latin pour Boileau ou l'anglais pour l'adolescent des années 60)  permet de dire des choses non considérées comme décentes, ou correctes, par la société dans laquelle on évolue.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! The notes for "building", "underground", and "stone" are particularly interesting since they suggest that the selection of English words isn't at all random, but makes use of words that had already gained currency among French speakers, particularly in a pop culture context for "underground" and "stone". (For "I've got the whole world in my hand", it's my fault for not giving enough context, but I feel like the Starmania song's tone is far enough removed from the old spiritual that the allusion would instead be to some intermediary that came in the meantime.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak As you might have guessed from my answer I'm more versed into 60/70's Anglo-American music than  into Starmania - I gather the two appeal to different kind of people. But still I think that if there was a special use of '"Ive got the whole world in my hand" I've been around this earth long enough to know about it. And long enough dabbling with Anglo-American influences on French culture. And I'm a French native.

Comment: I don't mean to challenge your knowledge, and I apologize if I seemed to. I meant that although the phrase must certainly go back to those spirituals, I wonder if it had been around long enough and developed in the meantime that the writer could be thinking of X person writing in the 60s who was thinking of Y person writing in the 40s who was thinking of Z person writing in the 20s. I guess it ultimately comes to the same thing, but the allusion might have a different significance depending on who brought it the most attention in that cultural context.

Comment: But I appreciate the depth of your answer and accept that you could have meant, and could be right, that the writer would have had in mind as the closest or most significant reference point the spirituals from the '20s and earlier.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I did not feel you were challenging my knowledge, my turn to apologize if the way I phrased made you think that.  Since most of us here are just nicknames I felt I had to point to the fact I was more at ease & reliable with this sort of topic than, for instance computing....

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: Et ça veut quoi stone? Vous ne le dites pas. Je pense que vous pensé a stoneD, pas stone. Non? On laisse tomber le D, n'est-ce pas? Putting a whole sentence  in another language is not like using a single word....

Comment: There's a technical name for music that references other music. It is common for songs to references other songs. I do not consider that using "English words" in a song.

Comment: @Lambie oui effectivement en Français  on laisse tomber le D. Je devrais dire "a laissé tomber" car  je n'ai plus entendu le mot utilisé dans une conversation en français depuis des décennies, mais c'est peut-être moi qui n'est plus les mêmes fréquentations.  Merci de l'avoir pointé, je vais mentionner la disparition du D.

Comment: @Laure Moi non plus. On prend de l'âge, heim? :)

Comment: oops.. qui n'**ai** plus...